# Wildcard sub-domain mapping in Ambassador API Gateway

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, ambassador, wildcard-mapping

I am using Ambassador API Gateway in my GKE as below:

```
apiVersion: getambassador.io/v2
kind: Mapping
metadata:
  name: my-service
spec:
  host: app.mycompany.com
  prefix: /
  service: my-service
```

However, I would like to map all sub domains (*.mycompany.com) and route to my-service

```
apiVersion: getambassador.io/v2
kind: Mapping
metadata:
  name: my-service
spec:
  host: *.app.mycompany.com
  prefix: /
  service: my-service
```

How to map wildcard subdomain?

Answer (score 3):

Based on this [documentation](https://www.getambassador.io/docs/latest/topics/using/headers/host/), you have to set the host as a regex pattern to match against your subdomains.

So in your case, you'd want this:

```
apiVersion: getambassador.io/v2
kind: Mapping
metadata:
  name: my-service
spec:
  host: "[a-z]*\\.app\\.mycompany\\.com"
  host_regex: true
  prefix: /
  service: my-service
```